# gitlab dont clone гитлаб не дает открыть проект

Tags: cmd, gitlab, git-clone

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если кто знает в чем проблема пожалуйста подробно скажите как и что сделать

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Ошибки и код лучше прилагать в текстовых блоках, чтобы исправить вопрос нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом. А ответ - у вас нет прав для клонирования данного репозитория, об этом говорит ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, Вы не импортировали в гитлаб свой публичный ключ.

Сделать это можно здесь:

[image: ключи]

[Что такое авторизация по ключам в гитлаб](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bxxh8Jne-QM) (ну, там про гитхаб, но в данном случае это не важно)

Кстати, успехов Вам в школе-21!

Comment: уже решил, да не сделал ключ, спасибо :)